# android - filtering orientation sensor

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm using the orientation sensor to measure the grade of a slope relative to a calibration point defined within the code. When the tablet is at a stable point to be measured, the output is rather jumpy (+/- ~.35). I want to put some sort of filter on the output of the sensor but I'm unsure how to really do that.

Here's my code so far:

within onCreateView()

```
sensorCalibrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    calibratedPitch = pitch;
                    adjustedRoll = roll;
                    // adjPitchDisplay.setText(Float.toString(Math.abs(calibratedPitch)) + "   ");

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sensor Calibrated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

Then some more methods

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor == mRotationSensor) {
        if (event.values.length > 4) {
            float[] truncatedRotationVector = new float[4];
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, truncatedRotationVector, 0, 4);
            update(truncatedRotationVector);
        } else {
            update(event.values);
        }
    }
}

private void update(float[] vectors) {
    final NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(5);
    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);

    float rads_to_Degrees = 57.29578F;

    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, vectors);
    int worldAxisX = SensorManager.AXIS_X;
    int worldAxisZ = SensorManager.AXIS_Z;
    float[] adjustedRotationMatrix = new float[9];
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, worldAxisX, worldAxisZ, adjustedRotationMatrix);
    float[] orientation = new float[3];
    SensorManager.getOrientation(adjustedRotationMatrix, orientation);

    pitch = orientation[1]*rads_to_Degrees;
    roll = orientation[2]*rads_to_Degrees; // roll will be implemented later on
    pitch = Math.abs(pitch);
    roll = Math.abs(roll);

    outputPitch = (calibratedPitch - pitch);
    final double tanPitch = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(outputPitch));
    outputGrade = tanPitch * 100D;

    outputGradeDisplay.setText("Current grade " + String.format("%.2f",outputGrade) + "%");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a quick and dirty low pass filter:

```
private static final double K = 0.9;

private void update (..) {
  ...
  pitch     = K*lastPitch + (1.0 - K)*(Math.abs(orientation[1] * rads_to_Degrees); 
  lastPitch = pitch;
  ...
}
```

where 0.0 <= K <= 1.0.

Values of K close to 1.0 will give you an output that is more stable but slower to respond to changes, values of K close to 0.0 will give an output that responds faster but is more 'jittery'.